# How do you reference an html document to another html document in a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Free Jokes!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>


        <div id="left"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#left').load("left.html");
        });
        </script>

        <div id="right"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#right').load("right.html");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The html is opening fine, but my left and right html documents aren't showing up. This may be from not correctly typing in the code. Was there anything I did wrong?

Is there any way I can reference my left and right html documents to this without using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

The load function attempts to make an ajax call to the location specified (remember, here in JavaScript we're on the client), so unless you specify absolute URLs, it won't retrieve from the correct location.
Furthermore, assuming that left.html and right.html are complete documents including doctype and `<head>` etc, that would produce invalid HTML.

Try the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Free Jokes!</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="final%20project.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>

        <iframe id="left" frameborder="0" style="border: 0;" src="left.html"></iframe>
        <iframe id="right" frameborder="0" style="border: 0;" src="right.html"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

While it's not perfect, it should at least display the pages correctly.

Comment: Does that mean if the html isn't on the web, you can't use jQuery for this?

Comment: Relative URLs are absolutely fine to use in JS. I really wouldn't recommend using iframes for this either; we exist in the years _after_ 2003

Comment: Yes, relative URLs are fine indeed - I'm not sure what I was thinking there.

I strongly disagree on iframes though. Generally, they are NOT a good solution here, of course - but there's even less of a reason to wait for document.ready to start loading the sub-pages' content. There's still good reasons to use them - no matter what year it is.

Comment: Where would you put the relative url?